# Lumen route without controller

Tags: routes, lumen

I have code in my lumen route like this

```
$route->group([
   "namespace" => "jobs",
   "prefix"    => "jobs"
], function() use ($router) {
   $route->get("/", "DummyController@index");
});
```

And i want to change some line to be like this

```
$route->get("/", "index");
```

Is it possible to make it that way? Thanks

NB:
I use lumen framework version 8.3.4 and php version 7.4

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Single Action Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class index extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return response()->json('Hello World');
    }
}
```

```
$router->get('/', 'index');
```